# revtex4の使い方がよくわかりません

Tags: latex, tex

論文執筆にあたりwindows64にrevtex4をインストールする必要があり、実際にAPSのHPからzip解凍し、Readmeを読んでいます。自分は今、texlive2018をインストールしており、システム変数のpathに

```
C:\texlive\2018\bin\win32
```

として通しています。revtex4-2のzipファイルの中のrevtexをコピーしそのファイルの中と同じ場所にshitagaki.texを保存し、実行すると

```
\documentclass{revtex4-2}
```

revtex4-2.clsがないとでます。
しかしshitagaki.texと同じディレクトリにrevtex4-2.clsはあります。
何が原因なのでしょうか

Comment: texfm_local=C:\texlive\2018\texmf-distとして、pathに以下のようにrevtex4-2.clsを書いてみました。C:\texfm_local\tex\latex\revtex\revtex4-2.cls\　こういったかんじでよいのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

TeX Live を使っているのであればパッケージの追加は `tlmgr install <package name>` で行います。
今回の件であれば `tlmgr install revtex4` となります。

それでもエラーが出るのであればエラーが出るソースコードやログの貼付けをすると回答がつきやすいでしょう。

Comment: それは拡張子がtexのファイル内で行うのですよね..?

Comment: いえ、端末(ウィンドウズでいうと「コマンドプロンプト」かな？)から `tlmgr install revtex4` と実行して、revtex4 を使えるようにしてから shitagaki.tex などを処理します。